# How to string count unique values in data strings

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to find common words having **5 unique vowels** (i.e: "aeiuo" without in a single word and without repetition)

*I tried this:*

```
library(tidyverse)
x<-c("appropriate","associate","available","colleague","experience","encourage","encouragi","associetu")
x[str_count(x,"[aeiuo]")>4]
```

*Note that words (**"encouragi"** and **"associetu"**) were used for the purpose of verifying my intended answer*

**the results I am generating are the following:**

```
[3] "available"   "colleague"  
[5] "experience"  "encourage"  
[7] "encouragi"   "associetu"
```

While I wanted to get only:
`"encouragi"   "associetu"` which fulfill the criteria of having 5 distinct vowels (i.e: "aeiuo").

Is there any function to serve as **string_count_unique**?? if yes, which one? if not, what other function might you recommend me to use so that I meet the set criteria?

thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be:

```
x[lengths(lapply(str_extract_all(x, "a|e|i|u|o"), unique)) == 5]

[1] "encouragi" "associetu"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using `strsplit` and `setdiff`. We loop over each string using `sapply`, we split each string into its letters, then we check if all vowels are present in the vector resulting from `strsplit`. If the length of the `setdiff` is greater than 0, one or more vowels are not present in the string.

```
keep <- sapply(x, FUN = function(x){
  length(setdiff(c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"), el(strsplit(x, "")))) == 0
})

x[keep]

# [1] "encouragi" "associetu"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are counting if the sum of ANY of `aeiou` is `>4`. What you want is to check that the count of `a` is `>0` AND that the count of `e` is `>0` and so on. So you could check the following:

```
x[str_count(x,"[a]")>0 & str_count(x,"[e]")>0 & str_count(x,"[i]")>0 & str_count(x,"[o]")>0 & str_count(x,"[u]")>0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `strsplit` could help you

```
> x[sapply(strsplit(x,""),function(v) sum(unique(v)%in%c("a","e","i","o","u"))>4) ]
[1] "encouragi" "associetu"
```